# How to read tab separated files in R to generate Scatterplot

Tags: r, graph, scatter-plot

I have a tab separated text file that has some data I saved in it from a python script.
Is there an easy way to import this data file to R and generate a scatterplot using this data with ageX column is on the X-axis and the memesY column is on the Y-axis?

I am looking for a simple scatterplot with points, and/or lines to include with my report.

Thanks!

This is a sample of the data saved in the file memesvsage.txt:

```
ageX    memesY
51  16

1255    1010

14  55

50  245

28  103

12  1

43  111

90  1

0   1

50  80

4   10
```

Comment: `mydata <- read.table("path/to/data.txt")` followed by `plot(x = mydata$ageX, y = mydata$memesY)` should do it. I would recommend saving the file as a .csv andysing read.csv instead, but that may just be personal preference.

Comment: I don't understand why would anyone downvote this question. The question is 100% legit, specific, and complete. That goes without saying since the entire answer is literally 2 lines and it fits in a tiny comment :-(

Comment: Likely because it is a question you could have worked out on your own, using various Google and/or stackexchange queries. It's very basic, which is why I answered in the comments, but everyone has to start somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a tab separated file:

```
mydf <- read.csv2('file.txt', sep = '\t', header = T)
```

To plot a simple scatter plot:

```
plot(x = mydf$ageX, y = mydf$memesY)
```

Comment: upvoting since it's basically the same as the answer I gave in the comment!

Comment: sry @PatrickWilliams :) your comment was uncomplete when I hit enter